# How to make nginx(proxy) cache the actual content instead of just the headers when a http 302/301 response is received by the proxy_pass server?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use nginx as a temporary http cache in order to minimize requests to content. My content is on multiple servers so I can't use a static proxy_pass parameter to the direct location but instead of that I use a rewrite to a php script:

```
rewrite      /([^/]+\.jpg)  /index.php?file=$1  break;
proxy_pass http://www.phpserver.com;
```

The php script(that would be http://www.phpserver.com/index.php) then returns a redirect with http code 301 to the actual file location(like http://www.contentserver1.com/filepath/file.jpg).

The problem is that nginx returns the redirect headers instead of retrieving,caching and returning the actual content.

So how do I make it to get the content from the actual server instead of just caching the headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx can work only as proxy. It doesn't know anything about logic of you application (site), it's just proxies requests, and can put to cache responses.

For make this schema work, you must remove `rewrite` section from nginx, and move this logic to phpserver.com. phpserver must download this file and output it to nginx. Even if it very hard operation, nginx would cache this response and when next request will be received, nginx will give response direct from his cache.

Comment: I understand the proxy concept, but the whole point is nginx to be the proxy in this case. This solution does not work for me though as I intend to use multiple instances of this nginx proxy with the actual application and having another single proxy won't do it. So I am interested in making nginx understand this very simple logic. I also tried to use the upstream directive for the same purpose but 404 failover didn't seem to kick in properly.

Comment: I've solved the problem through a upstream pool. Thank you for your answer.